# Machine Learning: Predicting target based on a feature

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn, pandas, data, prediction

I have a `df` looks as follow:

[image]

-It is very likely that the same `feature1Xfeature2Xfeature3` combination will appear multiple times.

-type values are in the range of 1..4.

I want to train a model, that for each `feature1Xfeature2Xfeature3` combination as input, will predict a `type` s.t this `type` will match to the lowest price. e.g, if there are two rows with the same `feature1Xfeature2Xfeature3 = [5.0, 3.6, 1.4]` combination, one has price of 5000 with type 3, the other has price of 2000 with type 1, then inputting the model with `feature1Xfeature2Xfeature3 = [5.0, 3.6, 1.42]` (a combination which is very close to the above one) will likely output 1 since it has lower price.

I've got some experience with models and learning using python and sklearn, but it sums to training a model with one target, which is not based on a specific feature.

The final goal is to try and fit several algorithms on this problem(KMeans, DecisinTree, NN..), and check who did the best.

Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

One quick thought is to use 1-NN ([k-Nearest-Neighbors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-nearest_neighbors_algorithm) with k=1).
This does not need any training (it is a lazy algorithm) and for each new sample you look up what is the nearest datapoint in your dataset.

In your case, when you try to classify a new sample you can set its price to 0.
If you use Euclidian distance as a distance metric for the 1-NN, then in case there are multiple points with the same feature values, the nearest one will be the one with the smaller price (assuming that prices are in the range [0, inf) to avoid complications with negative prices).

In summary, what you need to do to classify a sample:

1. Set the sample's price to 0.
2. For each data point in your dataset:
   3. Calculate the Euclidian distance between the sample and the data point.
3. Use the type of the data point with the minimum distance from the sample as the classification value for the sample.

Comment: Thanks, sounds good but I rather create a generic df s.t multiple models can fit on.

Comment: In that case, why do you leave the price out of the features in your description? You need to add it in the feature set and augment the new samples with a dummy price value (e.g. 0 as I suggested). Then you can evaluate any model you like. Most probably the 1-NN will have the optimal performance, as it is doing exactly what you described. The other models will try to learn this in a more complex way and may or may not perform as well.

Comment: Gotcha, I'll take your approach. what about dropping duplicates of `feature1Xfeature2Xfeature3` and taking only the row with the minimal price, then evaluate the model based on this data?

Comment: Well, this is cheating on your original problem :-) Sure, you can do that but the model evaluation will probably return different results.

Comment: Thanks. I've implemented your approach (1-NN with euclidean dist), but the results(based on accuracy and roc) are not as high as I thought they will be (around 25% accuracy and roc). I've fitted my model on the original data, and used price=0 on the test test. I thought of giving more weight to the price feature when calculating the distance, but that can pull me to a low price regardless of the other features. Any suggestions?

Comment: Is your train data well distributed over the input features ? does it have all possible range of values for the input features ?

Comment: It is hard to tell without having access to your dataset. Could you perhaps share it?